# Polar decomposition corollary

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a compact operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Let $|T|=(T^*T)^{0.5}$. By the polar decomposition theorem there is a partial isometry $S$ of the closure of Im$(|T|)$ such that $T=S|T|$. Let $(e_{n})$ be the orthonormal sequence of eigenvectors of $|T|$ with corresponding eigenvalues ${\lambda}_{n}$. Prove that the sequence $(x_{n})$ defined by $x_{n}=Se_{n}$ is orthonormal.

My attempt: If ${\lambda}_{n}$ is non-zero, then $e_{n}$ is in $\mathrm{Im}|T|$ so since $S$ is an isometry on there, $x_{n}$ has norm 1. But if ${\lambda}_{n}$=0, then $e_{n}$ is in the kernel of $|T|$, which is the orthogonal complement of the closure of
$\mathrm{Im}(|T|)$ so $Se_{n}$=0 which would contradict $x_{n}$ having norm 1. So I am missing something here. Also, why would $\langle x_{n},x_{m}\rangle=\langle Se_{n},Se_{m}\rangle=0$ for distinct $n,m$?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, some of the $x_n$ might be zero: note that all $x_n$ belong to the image of $T^*$, which could perfectly be finite-dimensional.

For your second question, $S^*Se_n=e_n$, as $S^*S$ is the projection onto the image of $|T|$.

Comment: The $x_{n}$ are eigenvectors of $TT^*$ so can't be zero. Could I someone take the difficult cases as arbitrary e.g. $x_{n}$=1 whilse still maintaining orthonormality? Also, I don't see how $<S^*Se_{n},e_{m}>=0$ @Martin Argerami

Comment: You are saying that $Se_n\ne0$ **always**? Have you tried any examples? I suggest you try with $T$ a rank-one projection and find the $x_n$ explicitly (hint: all but one will be zero). As for the other question, $$\langle Se_n,Se_m\rangle=\langle S^*Se_n,e_m\rangle=\langle e_n,e_m\rangle=\delta_{n,m}.$$

Comment: ok sorry I can ignore the eigenvector assocaited to zero

Comment: Of course, but in that case you might end up with finitely many $x_n$.

Comment: yes thats fine. This is the singular value decomposition of a compact operator if you're interested. Eigenvectors associated to zero contribute nothing to the sum so we can leave them out.